# iOS CenteralManager Not Calling Back on State Change

Tags: swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am writing my first BLE app in Swift and have hit a snag.  My central manager state change event handler is only being invoked when the app starts and the manger is initialized in viewDidLoad().  I can turn BLE off and on without a call back.  Code snippet below; any help will be appretiated.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CBCentralManagerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate
{
    //MARK: Properties

    var btManager: CBCentralManager!


    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Initialize CoreBluetooth Central Manager
        btManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
    }


    // Called when BLE changes state
    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager)
    {
        switch central.state
        {
            case .poweredOn:
                NSLog("BLE powered on")

            case .poweredOff:
                NSLog("BLE powered off")

            case .unsupported:
                NSLog("BLE unsupported")

            case .unauthorized:
                NSLog("BLE unauthorized")

            case .resetting:
                NSLog("BLE reseting")

            case .unknown:
                NSLog("BLE unknown")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code looks perfectly fine to me, and I've worked with Core Bluetooth many times. What version of iOS and Xcode are you running this on? There was some major bugs with Core Bluetooth between iOS 11 and iOS 11.2.

Comment: It’s weird.  Xcode 9.3.1 and iOS 10.13.4

Comment: Also, I am getting the device discovery, connect and disconnect call backs.